# Deciding on session ID string lengh to assure uniqueness

Tags: session

When a session ID is created, the ID isn't checked for uniqueness usually. Verifying uniqueness is a big overhead when dealing with billions of records.

I was wondering what length of a random session ID string should be enough to rely on for uniqueness in a production service, as big as Gmail for example.

Any other suggestions to maintain a proper session uniqueness will be welcome.

Thanks,

Roy.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you have a fairly good random number generator, a random 128-bit ID (such as a GUID) should be always unique in practice (mathematically speaking, there's a tiny tiny chance that there will be duplicates, but trust me, it's not going to happen. The universe will collapse in a giant black hole before there will be a duplicate GUID.)

Answer (score 3):

Instead of randomly generating your own number, why not...

- Use a [GUID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_Unique_Identifier) (128-bit)
- Use a string contained of the year, month, day, hour, minute, second, milliseconds or nanoseconds

If you use a 128-bit random number, then you have a 1 in 3.40282366921e+38 chance of getting a duplicate.  Assuming your numbers are truly random.

Answer (score 0):

A SHA-256 hash of some piece of user data and the current full time with as much resoution as is available should get you something sufficiently unique.